# How to parseint a combined POSTed object data types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a combined data types POSTed to API. I would like to parseInt() some of theses data (Price, vat, status, company_id).
Trying to POST the form gets me an Error :

```
POST https://api.factarni.tn/article/create 420
```

Also, in Console.dev-Network tab, it response with invalid data (that's why i need to parseInt specific strings like price, vat, status and company_id:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid data",
  "code": 400,
  "date": "2022-09-11T14:04:53.903Z",
  "level": "error"
}
```

My app is responding on console.dev-Network-payload with:

```
{
  "code": "",
  "article": "",
  "price": 0,
  "vat": 0,
  "status": 0,
  "company_id": 0,
  "Code": "code1",
  "Article": "article1",
  "Price": "10",
  "Vat": "20",
  "Status": "30",
  "Company_id": "40"
}
```

You can notice that application trying to send the initial states of useState AND the entred values in form. **How to make my application send only inputed form values and parsingInt the Price, vat, status and company_id values?**

My code:

```
const New = ({ inputs, title }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    code: "",
    article: "",
    price: 0,
    vat: 0,
    status: 0,
    company_id: 0,
  });

  function handle(e) {
    const newdata = { ...data };
    newdata[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newdata);
    console.log(newdata);
  }

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await fetch("https://api.factarni.tn/article/create", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...qw2QWltkyA",
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="New">
          //...
            <form>
              //...
              {inputs.map((input) => (
                <div className="formInput" key={input.id}>
                  <label>{input.label} </label>
                  <input
                    type={input.type}
                    placeholder={input.placeholder}
                    onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
                    id={input.label}
                    value={data.form}
                    name="data"
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
              <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
            </form>
          //...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: A stab in the dark, but replace the button with `<input type="submit" />` and then add `onSubmit` to your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Normalize`:

```
const normalize = (v) => ({
    code: v.code,
    article: v.article,
    price: Number(v.price),
    vat: Number(v.vat),
    status: Number(v.status),
    company_id: Number (v.company_id),
})

//...
const addUserDetails = async () => {
    await addUser(normalize(user))
}
```